# Error Keeps Appearing When Using 'raw_input' Python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5

On Python 3.5.1, whenever I enter this:

```
print ("How old are you?"),  
age = raw_input()  
print ("How tall are you?" ),  
height = raw_input()  
print ("How much do you weigh?"),  
weight = raw_input()

print ("So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight))'
```

It always tells me that 'raw_input' is not defined

'How old are you?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Sara/School Work/Computer Science/Python Practice/3.py", line 2, in 
    age = raw_input()
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined'

> > > 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` which is Python 2.x function

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3, you should use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`.

Comment: Thanks, Ive Spent legit an hour stuck on this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use input() instead of raw_input() in Python 3.